# the particle in 1-D box momentum and total energy(P.E + K.E (x))

Tags: homework, quantum-chemistry

Employing the particle in 1-D box can momentum and total energy(P.E + K.E (x)) can be measured simultaneously?

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.SE! If you had any questions about the policies of our community, you can ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help) or take a ‎‎[tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) of the website.‎

Comment: @MARamezani The particle in the box is a classical model in quantum chemistry and found in standard textbooks on physical chemistry by Moore & Hummel or Wedler or .... From the point of view of a slightly more experienced chemist, the matter itself is definitely on-topic. Whether this could/should be closed due to the lack of personal effort is another question.

Comment: My bad then @KlausWarzecha. I just told myself that "momentum", "potential energy", "kinetic energy" are more physics, without further digging into the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As this is obviously a homework problem, I'll just give you a hint:

Observables can be measured simultaneously with arbitrarily small uncertainties if their operators commute. Compute the [commutator](http://vergil.chemistry.gatech.edu/notes/quantrev/node18.html) of the momentum and particle-in-a-box Hamiltonian operators; if the commutator is zero, the answer to your question is "yes".